# Issue with neural prophet for R

Tags: python, r, prophet

I am having issues accessing neuralprophet.

```
remotes::install_github("AlbertoAlmuinha/neuralprophet", force = TRUE)
```

```
library(reticulate)

Sys.setenv(NPROPHET_PYTHON =
'/Users/rachelalaynahall/anaconda3/envs/climate/.conda')

library(neuralprophet)
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)
library(timetk)
```

After setting up a python environment with neural prophet in it.

```
library(neuralprophet)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘neuralprophet’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'neuralprophet', details:
  call: python_config_impl(python)
  error: Error running '/Users/rachelalaynahall/anaconda3/envs/climate/.conda/python': No such file.
>
```